# Make automapper cache the object if met more than once

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there any way to make automapper do not clone the same object but rather use a single object if it is met more than once in hierarchy?

Basically, I have a big array of different objects, that all reference the same object. When I map this collection with AutoMapper, it produces an array of objects where each object references a new cloned object. All these cloned object are not equal by reference anymore. This ends up in an out of memory issue for me.

Is there a way to configure some kind of cache for AutoMapper?

I've tried `.PreserveReferences()` in AutoMapper config, but that didn't do what I want. I think this works only for circular references.

**Update.**

Code example I test `.PreserveReferences()` with.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<A, MA>().PreserveReferences();
                cfg.CreateMap<B, MB>();
            });

            var b = new B();
            var a1 = new A() { Ref = b };
            var a2 = new A() { Ref = b };
            Assert.AreNotSame(a1, a2);
            Assert.AreSame(a1.Ref, a2.Ref);

            var ma1 = Mapper.Map<MA>(a1);
            var ma2 = Mapper.Map<MA>(a2);
            Assert.AreNotSame(ma1, ma2);
            Assert.AreSame(ma1.Ref, ma2.Ref); // This fails.
        }

        class A { public B Ref { get; set; } }
        class B { }

        class MA { public MB Ref { get; set; } }
        class MB { }
```

Comment: You are right about the PreserveReferences, that is for circular references. About your question, wouldn't it be easier (and more performant) to perform a distinct operation on your collection before you start to map it?

Comment: @hbulens That won't help. Before start I have an array of objects `[A, B, C, D...`] which all reference to the same object `X`. When I map this collection with AutoMapper, I receive an array of objects `[MA, MB, MC, MD..]` but now they point each to a corresponding `[XA, XB, XC, XD...]`. I also do not want to do much of a manual work here - the idea behind using AutoMapper is to simplify things. Otherwise I don't need AutoMapper at all

Comment: PreserveReferences should work.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Please see update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identity is preserved per Map call.

```
void Main()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<A, MA>().PreserveReferences();
        cfg.CreateMap<B, MB>().PreserveReferences();
    });

    var b = new B();
    var a1 = new A() { Ref = b };
    var a2 = new A() { Ref = b };

    var ma = Mapper.Map<MA[]>(new[]{a1, a2});
    (ma[0] == ma[1]).Dump();
    (ma[0].Ref == ma[1].Ref).Dump();
}

class A { public B Ref { get; set; } }
class B { }

class MA { public MB Ref { get; set; } }
class MB { }
```

Comment: Wow! This was totally unobvious to me. Thanks, works perfectly